# Good counter to Possession in Dominon: Alchemy

Tags: dominion, dominion-alchemy

It seems like Possession in Dominion: Alchemy is one of those cards that only very experienced players really know how to counter. Heck, I tend to see myself as an experienced Dominion player and I don't really see any ways to counter Possession at all, besides for the obvious way of trying to accumulate more Possessions than the other player(s).
Does anyone have any idea as to a reasonable counter of Possession?

**Disclaimer:** I do not own Alchemy, (but have played with it before), and have heard rumors from friends who **have** played with Possession before that it is an exceedingly powerful card and incredibly difficult, if not impossible to counter

Answer (score 9):

A good discussion with lots of tips to that exact same question is here: http://forum.dominionstrategy.com/index.php?topic=10001.0.

In general, more often than not you can just ignore Possession. It's really expensive, and on many boards, you can just get enough points without it that your opponent who is going for it will be too far behind. Remember that if you have $6 and a potion, then if that Potion had been a silver instead, you'd have $8 for a Province.

Attack cards are another good counter. If your opponent wants to make the best out of the extra turn, he'll have to play cards that hurt his own deck. Be careful to not build a super strong deck that can buy many Provinces each turn; but if your opponent can't do more than buy one Province or Duchy on the extra turn, then he's not getting a lot of use out of the Possession.

If the Kingdom makes it possible to have a deck that can play many Possessions per turn, then the best thing may be to get Possessions yourself and play as many as you can.

Answer (score 4):

A Goons strategy counters perfectly.  Opponent only gains cards not VP tokens, so if you have a deck of nothing but +actions +cards and Goons, it is difficult to lose to possession.

Comment: As of the release of Dominion: Empires, Possession has received errata saying that the player who played Possession *does* receive all tokens (including Victory Point, coin and Debt tokens) received on the turn, so this no longer works.

Answer (score 2):

Bear in mind that Possession is **not** an Attack. Why? Because all it (normally) does is burn through your hand and deck. Your trashed cards come back. Its purpose is to give the player an extra turn - it just does it with your cards. That churn of cards can be very beneficial because the cards you most recently bought are usually better cards, so cycling your deck gets them into your hand faster than just you taking your turns.

So as mentioned, it is a **very** expensive card. You could buy other expensive cards instead that could be useful much more quickly. Consider you must 1) buy a Potion; 2) get that Potion and 6 coin in play in one turn to buy the Possession; 3) wait for it to appear and play it. In the mean time I could have purchased (say) Silver and Gold, or even better cards.

Also be alert for cards that can make Possession much more powerful. If your Possession victim has Ambassador and Province in hand, well it could be returned to the Supply for you to gain. Remodel Province for Gold? Very nice (but your victim does not lose the Province). Masquerade a Gold to my opponent? Excellent. Those are times you want the Possession.

Comment: Your first two paragraphs don't really answer the question; they are more of a *hey, Possession isn't THAT bad*...

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 Explaining why it's not that bad is an answer, though it's implicit: it's just saying that you don't really *have* to counter it. And the second paragraph is a more direct answer: it says just counter it by doing something else productive, not by trying to actually deal with the Possession somehow.